# date and time control format

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, datetime

I have used Ajax calender extender to display date in Date_Box and then numeric up down extenders to chose time...

Here is my code:

```
<td bgcolor="#969ECD">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="Date_Box" runat="server" Width="85px"></asp:TextBox>&nbsp;

            <br />
             <div style="height: 4px"></div>

            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtHour" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="txtHour_NumericUpDownExtender" 
                runat="server" Enabled="True" Maximum="12" Minimum="1"  
                TargetControlID="txtHour" Width="70" >    
            </ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtMinute" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="txtMinute_NumericUpDownExtender" 
                runat="server" Enabled="True" Maximum="59" Minimum="1" 
                TargetControlID="txtMinute" Width="70" >
            </ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender>

            <asp:TextBox ID="txtDayPart" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender ID="txtDayPart_NumericUpDownExtender" 
                runat="server" Enabled="True" RefValues="AM;PM" TargetControlID="txtDayPart"  Width="70">
            </ajaxToolkit:NumericUpDownExtender>

            <asp:Button ID="Update" runat="server"  Text="Update" 
               onclick="Update_Click1" />
            <br />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

     <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="Date_Box" PopupPosition="TopRight"  >
     </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
```

Now functionality wise the only problem is when i write something in the textbox other than the normal format and click the update button it lets me accept the values instead it should not let it write anything else other than the date format.. eg no alphabets in the textbox..

This i can still figure out, using some exception message...

but now the main problen is the look of the control. The numeric extender buttons are too big and the line format is not good, also there is lots of space between the three time textboxes... is there a way to make this look neat>>>

How can i solve the problem... any suggestions???!

here is the image link http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?05945773e0.jpg
[alt text](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?05945773e0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing to do is to assign your numeric extenders a `CssClass` property, and use css to fix the layout issues.

Comment: i dont know how to use css property of the numeric extender buttons coz they come up automatically... thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use asp:RegularExpressionValidator to validate textbox contents:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahwtc9e.aspx

The documentation for NumericUpDown specifies you can use custom images for the updown buttons:
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/NumericUpDown/NumericUpDown.aspx

Comment: yes but to get a similar neat image of arrows one over the other is what i am not able to find.. what i get is up down arrows next to each other and they tale up space.. can help me find an image for this.. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try the FilteredTextbox from the ajax control kit found [here](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/FilteredTextBox/FilteredTextBox.aspx).
It will prevent typing into the box if they do not meet certain criteria.
Hope this helps
Tom